# use htmlspecialchars if it is not used?

Tags: php, database, security, htmlspecialchars, html-escape-characters

I have not followed rule which is

*Best Practice: Always use htmlentities for displaying data in a browser. Do not use htmlentities for storing data.*

And I have used htmlentities for storing data so I should not use htmlentities each time when I display it.But I saw that if someone can access my db and wrote script tag he can run script in all users data.I didn't followed rule because I thought that it can be slow to use htmlentities each time when display data.

So is there way to solve this issue?I think that solution can be use htmlspecialchars if it is not used.How can I do that?Should I delete all datas and wrote all script again that use htmlentities only when display in browser?

**Updated**

I found html_entity_decode() like below:

```
function escape($string){

$string = html_entity_decode($string,null,'UTF-8');
return htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

is that best way to do this.If I do so will I 100% able to reverse all and escape if it is not escaped?

Comment: You should use prepared statements for storing data. No need for htmlentities.

Comment: @Twinfriends no I have used prepared statement but problem is display data,I have used htmlentities to store data so I should not use htmlentities each time when I display it,but I recognize that if someone get access to database and change some data to script tag he can run javascript on user browser